# Is it possible to create a panalized node in code?

Tags: 7, panels

Is it possible to create a [Panelized](http://drupal.org/project/panelizer) node programatically?

Perhaps something like the following:

```
$node = new stdClass;
// ... Set other properties  
node_save($node)

// Then somehow add panalizer , layout, panels 
// Something like:
$panelizer = array ( 'nid' => $node->nid )

//save it
panelizer_save_node_panelizer($panelizer)  

// add existing panels/panes to the node 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure that your content type is *panelized* (you've *panelizer* link at `/admin/structure/types`).
2. Double check the Panelizer settings of that content type, for instance whether to '*Provide an initial display named "Default"*' (at `/admin/structure/types/manage/%`).

Above 2 steps can be achieved programatically by either exporting `panelizer_defaults` component into Features code:

```
features[panelizer_defaults][] = node:my_content_type:default
```

or define them using `hook_panelizer_defaults` manually.

At this point all your created nodes should be panelized automatically and the settings should be available in node object at `$node->panelizer['page_manager']`.

Still not sure if your node is panelized or not? Run this via `drush` (where 123 is your node id):

```
$ drush eval "print_r(node_load(123)->panelizer['page_manager']);"
```

and if you'll see an object printed out, your node is panelized.

Then if you would like to create/re-create panel display associated with the node, try the following code:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$old_display = $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display;
$new_display = panels_save_display($display);
$node->panelizer['page_manager']->display = &$new_display;
$node->panelizer['page_manager']->display_is_modified = TRUE;
node_save($node);
// Clear caches just in case.
ctools_include('object-cache');
ctools_object_cache_clear('panels_node_display_cache', $node->nid);
$did = is_numeric($new_display->did) ? $new_display->did : FALSE; // Your display id.
```

The same thing can be achieved on newly created code by creating a `panels_new_display();` instead and assign it to `$node->panelizer['page_manager']->display`.  Also note that the display should be only saved once (not on every node save), then it can be modified based on your needs.

See also:

- [How to attach node into panelized node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165905/how-to-attach-node-into-panelized-node)
- [Updating Panelizer content programmatically](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/updating-panelizer-content-programmatically)

Comment: Tank you for `$node->panelizer['page_manager']->display_is_modified = TRUE`, I was missing it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried myself, but taking a quick look at the [Upgrade path from Panel Nodes to Panelizer](https://drupal.org/node/1353542), we can find that the step that seemingly converts Panel Nodes into Panelized Nodes, is `db_insert('panelizer_entity')`.

This is further confirmed by a look into Panelizers `PanelizerEntityDefault.class.php`, where the method `public function hook_entity_insert($entity)` also does a `drupal_write_record('panelizer_entity', $panelizer);`

Hardly a nice step by step guide, but hopefully this should get you going.

Comment: I think this for drupal 7? I am working with drupal 6. Sorry I failed to mention that.

Comment: The table is called `panelizer_node` in D6, but I believe it's mostly the same.

Comment: What I really wanted to be able is to be able to recreate the node and especially what is under node/[nid]/panelizer/content like panels and panes..etc. I asked about exporting it to code in the project queue and was told there is no such feature for nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I use a workaround using a db_select and a db_update.

```
$nid = $node->nid;
$p_name = 'node:*panelizername*';

//Get the panel-info
$p_defaults = db_select('panelizer_defaults','d')
->fields('d')
->condition('d.name', $p_name, '=')
->execute()
->fetchAssoc();

//Remove fields that are node in the panelizer_entity
unset($p_defaults['pnid'],$p_defaults['name'],$p_defaults['title'],$p_defaults['panelizer_type'],$p_defaults['panelizer_key'],$p_defaults['access']);

//Update panelizer_entity
$u_query = db_update('panelizer_entity')
->fields($p_defaults)
->condition('entity_type', 'node')
->condition('entity_id', $nid)
->condition('name', $p_name);

/*dpm($u_query->arguments());
dpq($u_query,FALSE,'Update');*/

$u_query->execute();
```