# How to attach node into panelized node?

Tags: 7, panels

I've got content type which panelized using Full page override. So I would like to attach an existing node into newly created node and assign it into the region as normally you would do this at `/node/%/panelizer/page_manager/content`.

How this can be achieved programatically?

---

So far I've the following code:

```
<?php
# Usage: drush scr panelizer-test.drush.php

# Input variables.
$content_type = 'my_content_type';
$node_title = 'Content 1';
$did = 811; // Hardcoded display id from panels_display table (e.g. bootstrap_threecol_stacked).

# Load ctools includes.
ctools_include('plugins', 'panels');
ctools_include('common', 'panelizer');
ctools_include('context');

// Find the node in order to attach it to panelizer.
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('type', $content_type)
  ->propertyCondition('title', $node_title)
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->range(0,1)
  ->execute();


if (!empty($entities['node'])) {
  // Load the node.
  $nid = current(array_keys($entities['node']));
  $node = node_load($nid);

  // Create an empty context object.
  $node_context = ctools_context_create('node', $node);
  $node_uuid = $node_context->data->uuid;
}

// Submit Panelizer content form (/node/%/panelizer/page_manager/content).
$new_pane = panels_new_pane('node', 'node');
$plugin = ctools_get_plugins('ctools', 'content_types', 'node');
$form_state = array(
  'contexts' => array( 'panelizer' => $node_context),
  'pane' => $new_pane,
  'plugin' => $plugin,
  'values' => array(
    'nid' => "$node_title [id: $nid]",
    'override_title' => TRUE,
    'override_title_text' => 'FOOBAR',
    'override_title_heading' => 'h2',
    'links' => FALSE,
    'build_mode' => 'teaser', // or: 'full'
    'op' => 'Finish',
  ),
  'op' => 'add',
  'subtype' => array('title' => 'Existing node'),
  'subtype_name' => 'node',
  'step' => 'form',
  'wrapper_callback' => 'ctools_wizard_wrapper',
  'conf' => array(
    'build_mode' => 'teaser',
    ),
  'no_redirect' => TRUE,
);
drupal_form_submit('ctools_node_content_type_edit_form', $form_state); // And save it.
if ($errors = form_get_errors()) print_r($errors);

// Submit Panelizer main form (/admin/structure/types/manage/%/panelizer/page_manager/content)
$display = panels_load_display($did);
$layout = ctools_get_plugins('panels', 'layouts', 'bootstrap_threecol_stacked');
$renderer = panels_get_renderer_handler('editor', $layout);
$form_state = array(
  'values' => array(
    'display_title[hide_title]' => '0',
    'display_title[title]' => '%node:title (foo-bar)',
    //'panel[pane][top]' => '12867,12868,12869,12870', // See: pids from panels_pane table
    //'panel[pane][left]' => '12860',
    'panel[pane][middle]' => "12861,12862,12863,new-$node_uuid", // We need to use new pane uuid, not node's uuid.
    //'panel[pane][right]' => '12865,12866',
    //'panel[pane][bottom]' => '',
    'op' => 'Save',
  ),
  'display' => $display,
  'renderer' => $renderer,
  'layout' => $layout,
  'no_redirect' => TRUE,
);
drupal_form_submit('panelizer_edit_content_form', $form_state); // And save it.
if ($errors = form_get_errors()) print_r($errors);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better approach by using the following function which uses modifies display in node it-self:

```
/**
 * Attach node into panelized node.
 *
 */
function example_attach_node_to_panelized_node($pnid, $nid, $region = 'middle') {
  $result = FALSE;
  $node = node_load($pnid);

  // Set default region based on layout.
  if (!$region) {
    switch ($node->panelizer['page_manager']->display->layout) {
      case 'landing_page':
        $region = 'primary';
        break;
      case 'sub_landing_page':
        $region = 'main';
        break;
      case 'bootstrap_threecol_stacked':
      case 'onecol':
        $region = 'middle';
        break;
    }
  }

  if (!$region) return; // Check if matching type.

  $panes = array();
  $my_block_pane_exists = FALSE;

  // Load the display.
  $display = $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display;
  $did = is_numeric($display->did) ? $display->did : example_resave_display($node);
  if ($display = panels_load_display($did)) {

    // Check if our pane is already there, if so, ignore the further processing.
    $panes = $display->content; // Get this display's panes.
    foreach ($panes as $pid => $pane) { // Loop through and add in our new pane.
      if ($pane->type == 'node' && $pane->subtype == 'node' && $pane->configuration['nid'] == $nid) {
        // If our node already exists we can skip this.
        $my_block_pane_exists = TRUE;
        return FALSE;
      }
    }

    // Attach our new panel.
    $uuid = ctools_uuid_generate();
    $new_pane = panels_new_pane('node', 'my_node', TRUE);
    $new_pane->uuid = $uuid;
    $new_pane->pid = "new-" . $uuid;
    $new_pane->panel = $region;
    $new_pane->shown = 1;
    $new_pane->configuration['nid'] = $nid;
    $new_pane->configuration['build_mode'] = 'teaser';
    $new_pane->configuration['link_node_title'] = FALSE;
    $new_pane->configuration['links'] = FALSE;
    $display->panels[$region][] = $new_pane->pid;
    $display->content[$new_pane->pid] = $new_pane;
    // Or: $display->add_pane($new_pane, $sourcePane->panel);

    if (!$my_block_pane_exists) {
      // Finished reordering pane's and save the panelized node.
      $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display = $display;
      $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display_is_modified = TRUE;
      $result = node_save($node);
      // Clear ctools caches.
      ctools_include('object-cache');
      ctools_object_cache_clear('panels_node_display_cache', $pnid);
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

In case the display is not initialized yet (it's in [`new` state](https://www.drupal.org/node/2537006)), you've to re-save the display in order to perform above operations.

```
/**
 * Re-save panelizer display.
 * See: https://www.drupal.org/node/2537006
 *
 * @param
 *   $nid (integer)
 *     panelized node id
 *
 */
function example_resave_display($node) {
  $node = is_numeric($node) ? node_load($node) : $node;
  $display = !empty($node->panelizer) ? $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display : FALSE;
  if ($display && !is_numeric($display->did)) {
    $new_display = panels_save_display($display);
    $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display = $new_display;
    $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display_is_modified = TRUE;
    node_save($node);
    ctools_include('object-cache');
    ctools_object_cache_clear('panels_node_display_cache', $node->nid);
  }
  return is_numeric($new_display->did) ? $new_display->did : FALSE;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
example_resave_display(800); // Use only in case the node is new.
example_attach_node_to_panelized_node(800, 123);
example_attach_node_to_panelized_node(800, 124);
```

See also: [Updating Panelizer content programmatically](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/updating-panelizer-content-programmatically) which the above functions were based on it.